# Use hexadecimal color as string in darken function

Tags: css, less

In a less style, I have a variable that is a string.

```
@colorString: 'DADADA';
```

I can turn it into a color:

```
@color: ~'#@{colorString}';
```

I can use @color to set some value from a style:

```
div { color: @color }
```

but I cannot use it with the darken() function (or any other built-in function that manages colors).
Example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,darken( @color , 20%), @color);
```

The compiler outputs
error evaluating function `darken`: color.toHSL is not a function

it seems that the @color is not a color (#DADADA) but rather is a string ('#DADADA') and the function can't *parse* it.

Any idea to solve this, without changing the @colorString (it mus be a string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the the string to color using `color()`.

```
@colorString: 'DADADA';
@color: color('#@{colorString}');
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, darken(@color, 20%), @color);
```

Docs: http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-color

Comment: I think this is the problem. I tried in my application, which uses 3.7.1 and the color() worked! Thanks!